# How to reuse the build for an Angular project

Tags: angular, configuration, continuous-integration, angular2-routing

How can I **reuse** my Angular builds so I do not have to build for every specific environment?

we need to find a way to manipulate the environments in runtime in Angular!

We have settings for each environment and we use **NG build --env=dev** and build for the dev environment. How can I change the configuration in QA, UAT and production environments?

Toolset: .Net Visual Studio Team Services, Angular 2

**Is there no way to do this at runtime? Are we stuck with the build time/design time?**

Also can we consider selecting environments based on our urls which has a postfix ?
https://company-fancyspawebsite-**qa**.azurewebsites.net

PS:We are using the Angular 2 environments folder and app settings files for each environment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of angular configuration do you have per environment ?
Could you share more details ?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7506), [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2508#issuecomment-257988755) for several approach on how this can be done.

Comment: we are using the Angular 2 environments folder and appsettings files for each environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a config service to supply editable config settings at run-time. 
(this is using angular-cli)

config.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

export interface Config {
    PageSize: number;
    EnableConsoleLogging: boolean;
    WebApiBaseUrl: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    private config: Config;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getConfigSettings(): Config {
        if (!this.config) {
            var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            Httpreq.open("GET", 'config.json', false);
            Httpreq.send(null);

            this.config = JSON.parse(Httpreq.responseText);

            if (this.config.EnableConsoleLogging)
                console.log("Config loaded", this.config);
        }

        return this.config;
    }
}
```

config.json located in my src folder

```
{
  "WebApiBaseUrl": "http://myWebApi.com",
  "EnableConsoleLogging": true,
  "PageSize": 10
}
```

add config.json to your assets in .angular-cli.json

```
{
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "assets": [
        "config.json"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

how to use it

```
export class MyComponent {
    private config: Config;

    constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
        this.config = configService.getConfigSettings();

        console.log(this.config.WebApiBaseUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to mark it as answer. My friend at work states this is impossible using this and having a single CI definition to inject runtime variables. it would be great to upload a sample angular project for me to show him as a PoC.

Comment: No problem, here is a GIT: https://github.com/medeirosrich/ConfigExample no matter if you build dev or prod you can edit the config.json output in your dist folder and the settings will be picked up at run time where ever you choose to deploy.

Comment: thanks I have appended the question as my coworker mentioned that. He is using the environments practice in Angular(2). Even though I have mentioned him our urls are fixed he is telling me that this can not be achieved using out of the box solutions and we need a custom one and this one is not the solution. It would be great if you can reply after the update.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you want can't be done out of box using the current implementation of angular-cli's environment settings. This is actively being discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855 .Hopefully what you want comes built-in soon, otherwise in the meantime you need to implement a custom work around.

Comment: Richard as far as I understand this solution which you propose will help us use one build definition and add/inject the environment variables right?

Comment: Hi Rifat, that's correct. At my company once QA signs off on a specific build, we can send that same build to customers and they use the config.json to configure environment specific variables. No need to rebuild for each customer.

Comment: maybe it is addressed here as well? https://gist.github.com/fernandohu/122e88c3bcd210bbe41c608c36306db9

Comment: Looks very similar to the solution I provided above. It uses http to get a json file. He's built in some resilience for errors and a switch for grabbing .json files based on env settings. Looks good to me.